# mysql - getting the last 10 unique months

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, grouping

I want to get the last 10 unique months where there have been events, stored as event_date as a mysql date. I am using coldfusion so could group the result but can't get that working as I would like.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT MONTH(event_date) AS month, YEAR(event_date) AS year, event_date from events
```

so ideally if there were no posts in August would be output as

september 2010
july 2010
june 2010
may

etc etc

Thanks.

R.

Comment: I am not really into cold fusion - and probably I just dont get what you want, but from a mysql point of view: can't you just use SELECT DISTINCT plus some LIMIT?

Comment: @ran2 - You should make that an answer. @Ross I think this is what is needed? `SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(event_date) AS month, YEAR(event_date) AS year from events ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC LIMIT 10;`

Comment: +1 @Martin Smith beat me to it ;) The key is to omit the "event_date" column from your results, so you only get the distinct month and year values. BTW: You might consider using different names, in case those are reserved words.

Comment: @Martin Smith, sorry for not making it answer. I was not sure if my suggestion was worthy of an answer. However, I was about to state what you just did :) Not going to get YOUR praise...

Comment: One of you guys should make it an answer .. ;)

Comment: @ran2 - Well I'm not putting an answer so I suggest you do before someone else does!

Comment: LOL... So finally I got some ups on my comment :) Don't even know what that's worth, but nice to have though...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(event_date) AS month, YEAR(event_date) AS year from events ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: yes that was the answer it was the extra event_date in the SELECT clause. Many thanks